# Gaps in derivation of thermodynamic property equations.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, operator-theory

If $h=h(T, P)$.

Does $ dh = \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial T}\right)dT + \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial P}\right)dP \Rightarrow h_2 - h_1 = \int_{T_1}^{T_2}\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial T}\right)dT + \int_{P_1}^{P_2}\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial P}\right)dP $ ?

If so, how?

I apologize for this, but I just haven't been able to find an appropiate justification for this operative behavior in any of the Calculus, Differential Equations and Thermodynamics books in my possession. I'm particular bugged by the "integration of differentials" and how it, before me, seems to damage the symmetry of the first equation in the statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now, the specific trouble is how could one go from $a$ to $b$ in the statement, e.g. by integrating both sides with respect to what? Also, according to the books, a differential of a two-variable function is itself a four-variable function, say, $dh=dh(T,P,dT,dP)$, and I know it can be used to approximate a value $h_2$ from a value $h_1=h(T_1,P_1)$, but that is of no use since there is no explicit function of $h$; as some of you know it can't be measured and the goal is simply finding a way for computing changes in it.

Comment: But the fashion in which one gets to this last instance doesn't make much sense to my unexperienced head.

Comment: Is it valid what thery're doing? Under which assumptions?